# Слово "чтобы" какого вида требует? НСВ или СВ?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Я заметил, что русские употребляют и то и то.
Есть ли правила?

Comment: "Чтобы" ничего не требует. Это [либо союз, либо частица](http://morphologyonline.ru/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B). Уточните, что вы имеете в виду. Пример какой-нибудь.

Comment: Вот например, если ставить после слова "чтобы" инфинитив... в каком виде должен быть он? Из этих предложений, какое правильное? 1) Надо учиться, чтобы добиваться успеха в жизни; 2) надо учиться, чтобы добиться успеха в жизни.

Comment: Добавьте пояснения в вопрос с помощью ссылки Edit. Оба варианта правильные, но имеют различные смысловые оттенки. Собственно, перфект и имперфект. Само по себе слово "чтобы", на котором вы почему-то акцентируете внимание, не определяет вид глагола. Он определяется смыслом того, что вы хотите выразить.